# All apps seem to be gone

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, internal-storage, internal-sd

I was using my Chrome on Android 4.1.2 on Samsung Galaxy S II and phone suddenly crashed. When phone restarted it looked like all apps are gone, even Google Play.

[image: Home¸screen]

App Drawer shows only standard apps like Camera, FM radio, Internet, Messaging, Phone, Samsung Apps etc. but all other cannot be seen there.

[image: Drawer 1] [image: Drawer 2]

Application Manager lists my apps under DOWNLOADED label, but instead of apps names (e.g. Chrome or Viber) it shows app IDs (com.android.chrome or com.viber.voip) and instead of app icons it shows some gray icon with labels Android and SD. Under ON SD CARD label it there are no apps. I don’t have external SD card.

[image: Apps Mgr - Downloaded] [image: Apps Mgr - On SD Card] [image: Apps Mgr - Running] [image]

I used Android System Recovery to wipe cache partition and it wiped cache for all except Chrome cache.

[image: Chrome cache]

What can be problem? How can I get my apps back?

Comment: Look at the appstore, check `my apps` => `Installed`. At least you can re-install from `all apps`.

Comment: @ott-- , he said that google play has even disappeared, he cannot do that.

Comment: @ott--, Csharper is right. I don’t even have Google Play. When I go to Google Play using my computer, and I try to install or uninstall, I get message that an app will be installed or uninstalled in a few moments, but nothing happens because Google Play on my phone is gone or cannot be started.

Comment: Maybe a factory reset can help with it. Since you don't have any external SD card, This issue is not hoped raise. Can you download anything using stock browser? Check for it. If not there might be issue with internal memory as far as i know about android.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (*insert reasons here*). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be some sort of faliure or glitch in your phone.

One way to fix this would be to factory reset your phone. by going to `Settings > Backup & Reset > Factory data reset.`

I would believe that there is nothing wrong with the SD card, so photos & music should be fine.

You can regain apps by then going to `Google Play Store > Swipe Left to Right > My apps` and install the apps back into your phone.

I hope this works.

Comment: I believe that this will work but I would like to save my data. Photos and music are fine, but Viber messages and organizer (DGT GTD) data are not reachable to me.
Is there any way to get them? Do I need to root my phone to do that? Is there some check disk or something that could help me?

Comment: @Domagoj It doesn't seem so. Even with a root application app backup tool. It wouldn't work, because the phone lost all your apps for some reason, including your apps. Getting that data back would most likely not be possible

Comment: @Domagoj There is also a possiblity the SD CARD is corrupted. Try plugging it back in and out. See if that will work.

Comment: I don't have external SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Go to widgets and click on google play and from there, add it to your 
home screen. From there download all of your apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but this may fix it:

The screenshot of the disabled apps shows the Android logo and an SD card (meaning you have an internal SD card, this is also evident from "Apps on SD card" tab). Go to Settings > Storage and select "Unmount" under the internal SD card (or "Mount"). Then reboot.

I had the same issue and that helped me (only when it happened to me, it was because I was using the USB Mass Storage option).

But the Google Play Store part did not happen to me. If it still does not appear, try installing a third party app store as a last resort. Or obtain root and use an app that installs apps as system apps to reinstall the Google Play Store.